# where is my still reachable memory (after valgrind memory check for c programs)?

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

When I am coding in language c these days, I keeps getting **still reachable** warnings after using **valgrind** to check memory of my c program **but I am never able to find them out**. I have read several articles on this and somebody say it is not a problem, some say that we could have problems when reusing the same code later. So I decided to make these **still reachable memrories** disappear. 

So the following is my c code. I really want to know where are my still rechable memories ? And how could I possibly **clean them up** ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _ddict_application_t{
    char *name;
    uint32_t code;
    struct _ddict_application_t *next;
} ddict_application_t;


ddict_application_t *parse_applications(void) {

    char *table[10] = {
        "the_first",
        "the_seoncd",
        "the_third",
        "the_fourth",
        "the_fifth",
        "the_sixth",
        "the_seventh",
        "the_eighth",
        "the_ninth",
        "the_tenth"
            };
    ddict_application_t *head = NULL;
    ddict_application_t *current = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(i==0) {
            head = g_new(ddict_application_t, 1);
            head->name = NULL;
            head->code = 0;
            head->next = NULL;

            head->name = strdup((const char*)table[i]);     
            head->code = i*37+21;
            head->next = current = g_new(ddict_application_t, 1);

            current->name = NULL;
            current->code = 0;
            current->next = NULL;
            continue;
        }
        current->name = strdup((const char*)(table[i]));

        current->code = i*37+21;
        if(i+1 == 10) 
            current = current->next = NULL;
        else
            current = current->next = g_new(ddict_application_t, 1);
    }
    return head;
}

void ddict_free(ddict_application_t *appl) {
    ddict_application_t *a = NULL;
    ddict_application_t *an = NULL;
    for(a = appl; a; a = an) {
        an = a->next;
        g_free(a->name);
        g_free(a);
    }

}

void print_applications(ddict_application_t *appl) {
    if(!appl) {
        fprintf(stderr, "application passed is NULL\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ddict_application_t *tmp = appl;
    while(tmp) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Application: %s [%u]\n", tmp->name, tmp->code);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ddict_application_t *appl = parse_applications();
    print_applications(appl);
    ddict_free(appl);
    return 1;
}
```

And when I run it on terminal with this on ubuntu:

```
gcc linked_list.c -o test -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 -g
```

And compile it with valgrind :

```
valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --leak-check=full -v ./test
```

Then valgrind gave me the following result :

```
Application: the_first [21]
Application: the_seoncd [58]
Application: the_third [95]
Application: the_fourth [132]
Application: the_fifth [169]
Application: the_sixth [206]
Application: the_seventh [243]
Application: the_eighth [280]
Application: the_ninth [317]
Application: the_tenth [354]
==2370== 
==2370== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2370==     in use at exit: 18,604 bytes in 6 blocks
==2370==   total heap usage: 28 allocs, 22 frees, 19,977 bytes allocated
==2370== 
==2370== Searching for pointers to 6 not-freed blocks
==2370== Checked 109,328 bytes
==2370== 
==2370== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 6
==2370==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2370==    by 0x4EC8102: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4EC8644: g_private_get (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4EA088C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E726CD: g_hash_table_new_full (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E9383A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==2370==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==2370== 
==2370== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==2370==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2370==    by 0x4E89700: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E72734: g_hash_table_new_full (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E9383A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==2370==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==2370== 
==2370== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==2370==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2370==    by 0x4E89700: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E7271F: g_hash_table_new_full (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E9383A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==2370==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==2370== 
==2370== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==2370==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2370==    by 0x4E896A8: g_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4EA08B2: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E726CD: g_hash_table_new_full (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E9383A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==2370==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==2370== 
==2370== 2,032 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
==2370==    at 0x4C2FB55: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2370==    by 0x4E89700: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4EA0B1B: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E726CD: g_hash_table_new_full (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E9383A: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==2370==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==2370== 
==2370== 16,384 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
==2370==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2370==    by 0x4E896A8: g_malloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x4E9384B: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.0)
==2370==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==2370==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==2370==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==2370== 
==2370== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2370==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2370==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2370==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2370==    still reachable: 18,604 bytes in 6 blocks
==2370==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: @BeyelerStudios I tried, but I have the same result as before.

Comment: @BeyelerStudios not at all.

Comment: Not sure if it could a problem, but to be consistent you should use `g_strdup`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried **g_strdup** but I got exactly the same result. I think **g_strup** isn't so diffrent from **strdup**, is it?

Comment: Don't post images of text! It is even easier just to copy/paste the text.

Comment: @Olaf I will change it :)

Comment: Is it just me, or does it seem that the memory leaks come from outside his main? Maybe some sort of glib initializations before main is called?

Comment: Libraries commonly allocate a fixed amount of stuff at startup and don't bother freeing it.   It's safe enough.  Freeing such stuff reliably and safely is extremely difficult if you are not an OS terminating a process, so lib developers don't do it.  In general, a completely 'clean' valgrind output at app close is some sort of unrealistic utopia dreamed up by profs and TA's.  Real world - not gonna happen.

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, it's right. I don't really need to care about these still reachable memories. I was just wondering where they came from and I finally found it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory locations being referenced are generated by the glib functions you're calling.

You're already calling `g_free`, so there's probably not much you can do about it.

Comment: Exactly, I then tried to replace all the **g_new** by **malloc**, and replace all to **g_free** by **free**, and then there was no **still reachable memory** anymore. You are right, we don't really need to care about these **still reachable** memory when using **glib**. But I am still very happy to have found where these still reachable memory came from.